# Multiple show/hide forms in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I want to have list of files in directory and a form below each of them that allows my users to name them. 
That's all clear - I made it in php, but now I want to have this list and hidden forms, and when I'm clicking on one of my file's name, the form shows under the clicked name.

Something like here: http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-sliding-div/#

Here is the code: http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

But it works in a way, that when i click on one of files, all forms shows or all hides. How to fix it to work only for clicked file?

JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/qbNrR/

**@UPDATE - SIMILAR PROBLEM**

Hey, I've got similar problem with submitting ajax forms - using this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

my forms are in div id=#upform and when i'm trying to submit any of them via $.ajax it submits only the first one, here's the code:

```
<script> 
 $(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        var txt = $(".tekst#test").val();
        var dataString = 'tekst=' + tekscior;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload/base",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('#upform').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message')
                    .html("<h2>described!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>thanks!</p>")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        $('#message')
                            .append("<img id='checkmark' src='http://artivia-dev2/i/check.png' />");
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});​
</script>
```

AND Here are my forms:

// ONLY THIS ONE IS SUBMITTED, EVEN WHEN I'M SUBMITTING THE SECOND ONE!

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
<div id="upform">
<form name="contact" action="">  
<input type="text" value="TESTFORM" class="tekst" id="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Send" />
<form>
</div> 


<div class="slidingDiv">
<div id="upform">
<form name="contact" action=""> 
<input type="text" value="TESTFORM" class="tekst" id="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Send" />
<form>
</div>
```

Comment: make it in jsfiddle site and will try help when i have break time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `next()` jQuery method. Then your code will look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(e) {
        $(e.target).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Hey, can you take a look at edited first post? I have a similiar problem, which I can't solve with this solution : ] Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try event.currentTarget to get the form that triggered the click event

Answer (score 0):

on click event use jquery like

```
$(this).show(); // or hide();
```

as in example

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
  //$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
  $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: It's not that - check on my fiddle : ) Thanks anyway1